# Bluez AVRCP "server" - How to provide track metadata?

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, music-player

It is very easy to get track metadata from a BT player with AVRCP - you just have to get property `"Track"` of `"org.bluez.MediaPlayer1"` interface.

But when the the player is implemented using Bluez (i.e. you stream data from Linux device to some other), how to provide track name, artist etc? With GATT service, I just register its obj path in GATTManager, there is no analogic way in Bluez...